# Difference between int(x) and (int)x

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a floating point number `x` and I want to convert it into an integer. Is there any difference between `int(x)` and `(int)x` in C++.
I am new to C++ coming from Python background and naturally I tried int(x) to convert x to an integer but reading about C++ I came across type-casting i.e. `(int)x` and in this case it also works.

I was wondering what's the difference between these two approaches and in a wider context which one to use where?

```
float x = 5.5;
cout<<int(x)<<endl; //outputs 5
cout<<(int)x<<endl; //outputs 5
```

Comment: IIRC `int(x);` is declaration for x. `(int)x;` is a type cast whose result is then ignored. But in your case, either has the same meaning, a type cast.

Comment: The only real difference is `int(x)` can't use types with spaces in their name.  `long long(x)` is invalid.  `(long long)x` on the other hand is.

Comment: @NathanOliver that sounds like a defect in the standard. Clearly they should amend it to allow `(long long)(x)`.

Comment: @HongOoi `(long long)(x)` is also valid.  You just can't do `long long(x)` or `unsigned int(x)` or any other 2+ word type

Comment: but `using ll = long long; ll(x);` is fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was trying to troll the C++ committee but the C++ committee has trolled me :(